# How to add private key while encrypting using bouncy castle in c#

Tags: vb.net

```
Private Function InitSignatureGenerator(ByVal compressedOut As Stream) As PgpSignatureGenerator
    Const IsCritical As Boolean = False
    Const IsNested As Boolean = False
    Dim tag As PublicKeyAlgorithmTag = m_encryptionKeys.SecretKey.PublicKey.Algorithm
    Dim pgpSignatureGenerator As New PgpSignatureGenerator(tag, HashAlgorithmTag.Sha1)

    pgpSignatureGenerator.InitSign(PgpSignature.NoCertification, m_encryptionKeys.PrivateKey)
    ' pgpSignatureGenerator.GenerateOnePassVersion(False).Encode(compressedOut)
    For Each userId As String In m_encryptionKeys.SecretKey.PublicKey.GetUserIds()
        Dim subPacketGenerator As New PgpSignatureSubpacketGenerator()
        subPacketGenerator.SetSignerUserId(IsCritical, userId)
        pgpSignatureGenerator.SetHashedSubpackets(subPacketGenerator.Generate())


        '   this function i am unable to decrypt, it shows error private key not in public key ring
    Next
    pgpSignatureGenerator.GenerateOnePassVersion(IsNested).Encode(compressedOut)
    Return pgpSignatureGenerator
End Function
```

Comment: original code in c#, i changed to vb.net

Comment: What is type of `m_encryptionKeys` object?

Comment: m_encryptionkeys contains three keys private public secretkey